# Split String contain Brackets in PHP

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have string like following format:

```
$string ='[(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename|filename][(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename|filename]';
```

I want to extract string for square and simple bracket and result set would be like

```
[0] =>(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)
[1] => filename
[2] => filename
```

How can i do it? I have tried below code:

```
explode("[" , rtrim($string, "]"));
```

But not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for this,

```
$re = "/\\[\\((.*?)\\)(.*?)\\]/s"; 
$str = "[(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename|filename][(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename|filename]'"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**output**

```
matches[1][0] => id,name,top,left,width,height,depth
matches[1][1] => filename|filename
```

See 
[regex](https://regex101.com/r/xL1oW5/3)

Comment: There might be possiblity that only one filename so no need to explode with |(pipe sign). If exist, need to check

Comment: I couldn't get you clearly. What's your expected output from the given string?

Comment: filename is dynamic so what if string like $string ='[(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename][(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename]';

Comment: so, if the string is like this,`[(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename|filename]` then you want to ignore pipe symbol ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$string ='[(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename|filename][(id,name,top,left,width,height,depth)filename|filename]';
$array = explode('][',$string);
$array = array_unique(array_filter($array));
$singleArr = array();
$singleArr[] = str_replace('[','',$array['0']);
$singleArr[] = str_replace(']','',$array['1']);

$singleArr = array_unique($singleArr);
//print_r($singleArr);

$blankArr = array();
foreach($singleArr as $val)
{
    $first = explode('|',$val);
    $blankArr['0'] = substr($first['0'],0,-8);
    $blankArr['1'] = substr($first['0'],-8);
    $blankArr['2'] = $first['1'];
}
print_r($blankArr);
```